# Separating characters in a string and assign its value to a variable

Tags: c, string, char, character

I wonder if it is possible in C to separate a string of characters in a text file and pass the value of each character to a char type variable.

For example:

If a txt file contains the code `13E65A`

The program would work so that

```
char a = 1
char b = 3
char c = E
char d = 6
char e = 5
char f = A
```

If this is possible what function would be best to do it with?

Thanks for responding.

Comment: you mean char c = 'E'

Answer (score 1):

Open the file with fopen and then use fscanf function:

```
fscanf(file_handle, "%c%c%c%c%c%c", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
```

a, b, c, d, e, f variables are chars as in your example

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to read the contents of a text file into a character array, then the c function fread() should be able to do what you are looking for. Here is a link to a good tutorial on the subject: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm